# What Can I use In this Code Instead of try-catch exception handling

Tags: java, jackson, jaxb

What Can I use In this Code Instead of try-catch exception handling?
I've tried to use The Java throws keyword to declare an exception Instead of try-catch exception handling but It is not being passed in the test cases. is there any other way to handle the exception here?
I was trying to remove some duplicate code, I marked the duplicate code with *** (I have the same code in 8 methods ), but it's using class object from try block of its own, if I create a method and use try catch block there as well then the parameter that i have to pass is still in try block, in the last line I've comment that out

```
AjaxResponseBean moveControl(@PathVariable Integer formId, @RequestBody AjaxRequestBean request) {
        try {
            Form form = formService.getFormWithDraft(formId);
            FormDraftData draft = formService.getFormWithDraft(formId).getDraft();

            String formXml = draft.getData();
            String id = request.getData().getControls().get(0).getId();
            String beforeId = request.getData().getControls().get(0).getBeforeId();

            JAXBContext jaxbControlContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlFormBean.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbControlUnmarshaller = jaxbControlContext.createUnmarshaller();
            XmlFormBean xmlFormBean = (XmlFormBean) jaxbControlUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(formXml));

            XmlFormBean.Control xmlControl = new XmlFormBean.Control(id);
            for (XmlFormBean.Control c : xmlFormBean.getControls()) {
                if (c.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                    xmlControl = c;
                    break;
                }
            }

            xmlFormBean.getControls().remove(xmlControl);
            int index = -1;
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(beforeId)) {
                index = xmlFormBean.getControls().indexOf(new XmlFormBean.Control(beforeId));
            }
            if (index == -1) {
                xmlFormBean.getControls().add(xmlControl);
            } else {
                xmlFormBean.getControls().add(index, xmlControl);
            }
//******************************
       Marshaller jaxbControlMarshaller = jaxbControlContext.createMarshaller();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            jaxbControlMarshaller.marshal(xmlFormBean, writer);
            form.getDraft().setData(writer.toString());
            formService.addForm(form);

            // AjaxResponseBean
            AjaxResponseBean response = new AjaxResponseBean();
            response.setResult("success");
            response.setData(request.getData());
            return response;


        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        AjaxResponseBean response = new AjaxResponseBean();
        AjaxDataBean data = new AjaxDataBean();
        data.setMessage("The client request failed.");
        response.setResult("failure");
        response.setData(data);
        //return MarshallerSomething(form, jaxbControlContext, xmlFormBean, request);
        return response;
//******************************
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the scenario here, "but It is not being passed in the test cases" it is not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to test for an exception scenario via the test case? If an exception occurs either you can catch that via try-catch block or throwback that at the calling method using throws. What is your requirement here?

Comment: Actually i was trying to remove some duplicate code, I marked the duplicate code with *** (I have the same code in 8 methods )take a look, but it's using class object from try block of its own, if I create a method and use try catch block there as well then the parameter that i have to pass is still in try block, in the last line I've comment that out,

Comment: If I have understood correctly you need to create a new method and pass some params but those params are defined inside the try block and you need to call the new method from outside of the try-catch block. If that is the case you can define the params outside the try block and initialize them inside the try block so that required params are available outside the try-catch block as well. Let me know if you need code as well will provide that in the answer block.

Comment: The params i'm passing ( JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlFormBean.class);) needs to be in the try block, otherwise showing compile time exception, and JAXBContext is different for each method , so i cant put that on the method that i'm creating to remove duplicate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mention the superclass of JAXBContext in params and pass the subclass as per method requirements so that common code can be taken out and moved to different methods even if it requires different implementations.

Let's say Context is the superclass for JAXBContext and JContext are its subclasses.

```
public void testMethod(Context con, String str){
//your logic here
}

Context c1 = new JAXBContext()
Context c2 = new JContext() 
testMethod(c1, "test1")
testMethod(c2, "test2")
```

You can try the below won't get compile-time exception

```
AjaxResponseBean moveControl(@PathVariable Integer formId, @RequestBody AjaxRequestBean request) {
        Form form = null;
        JAXBContext jaxbControlContext= null;
        XmlFormBean xmlFormBean = null;
            try {
                form = formService.getFormWithDraft(formId);
                FormDraftData draft = formService.getFormWithDraft(formId).getDraft();

                String formXml = draft.getData();
                String id = request.getData().getControls().get(0).getId();
                String beforeId = request.getData().getControls().get(0).getBeforeId();

                jaxbControlContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlFormBean.class);
                Unmarshaller jaxbControlUnmarshaller = jaxbControlContext.createUnmarshaller();
                xmlFormBean = (XmlFormBean) jaxbControlUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(formXml));

                XmlFormBean.Control xmlControl = new XmlFormBean.Control(id);
                for (XmlFormBean.Control c : xmlFormBean.getControls()) {
                    if (c.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) {
                        xmlControl = c;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                xmlFormBean.getControls().remove(xmlControl);
                int index = -1;
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(beforeId)) {
                    index = xmlFormBean.getControls().indexOf(new XmlFormBean.Control(beforeId));
                }
                if (index == -1) {
                    xmlFormBean.getControls().add(xmlControl);
                } else {
                    xmlFormBean.getControls().add(index, xmlControl);
                }
//******************************
                Marshaller jaxbControlMarshaller = jaxbControlContext.createMarshaller();
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                jaxbControlMarshaller.marshal(xmlFormBean, writer);
                form.getDraft().setData(writer.toString());
                formService.addForm(form);

                // AjaxResponseBean
                AjaxResponseBean response = new AjaxResponseBean();
                response.setResult("success");
                response.setData(request.getData());
                return response;


            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            AjaxResponseBean response = new AjaxResponseBean();
            AjaxDataBean data = new AjaxDataBean();
            data.setMessage("The client request failed.");
            response.setResult("failure");
            response.setData(data);
            return MarshallerSomething(form, jaxbControlContext, xmlFormBean, request);
            //return response;
//******************************
        }
```